# Can't get list of files in directory in pam_exec.so script

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, sshd, pam

I'm running a custom script on every ssh login to notify me if there was an a login by an unknown IP address that has not been added to a custom whitelist. I'm using **pam_exec.so** to check for this whenever a user logs in. This is working fine so far, I'm getting the notification I want whenever I log in and my own ip is currently not on the whitelist I defined.

Only problem is I have a for loop in the script that is supposed to tell me what website configurations exist on the server. To do this, it tries to get all files in **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled**. Since there's currently a bunch of servers with non-descriptive hostnames it would be convenient to know what's running on it when I get the notification. When I run the script manually there is no issue with this but when I use pam to automate it, the string with configuration names comes up empty.

Is there any way to get the file names?

Here is the script, its permission settings and the line I added to pam configuration to make it work:

**/root/sh/login-notifiy.sh**:

-rws--x--x 1 root root 1296 Jun 14 07:45 login-notify.sh*

```
#!/bin/sh

# Change sender depending on where the notification should go

sender="webserver@test.com"
target="receiver@test.com"
client_ip="${PAM_RHOST%% *}"
user=$PAM_USER

# Check if the session is open

if [ "$PAM_TYPE" != "close_session" ]; then
        # Check if client ip is on the whitelist
        if grep -Fxq "$client_ip" /etc/ssh_ip_whitelist; then
        :
        else
        host="`hostname`"

        # Get all active website configurations on the server
        host_websites=""
        for entry in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*
        do
                config_name="$(basename $entry)"
                host_websites+="\n${config_name}"
        done

        subject="SSH Login: user $user from $client_ip on $host"
        # Message to send, e.g. the current environment variables.
        message="A new ssh login has been detected:\nhost - $host\nuser - $user\nip - $client_ip\n\nThe following website configurations exist on this server: $host_websites\n\nIf you trust this IP, please ask your server administrator to add it to the file /etc/ssh_ip_whitelist on this server. To quickly add an IP, connect to the server, change to root user and use:\n\necho \"<trusted ip>\" >> /etc/ssh_ip_whitelist"

        # Send the email
        echo "Subject: $subject\n$message"|/usr/sbin/sendmail -r $sender -t $target
        fi
fi
```

**/etc/pam.d/sshd**:

```
session optional pam_exec.so seteuid /root/sh/login-notify.sh
```

Comment: Are you sure you are running the script with `/bin/sh` in both cases? iirc string concatenation using `+=` is a non-POSIX feature

Comment: @steeldriver Well turns you're right, apparently my mind went elsewhere for a bit and I didn't think the concatenation part would be an issue. Thanks for getting me on the right track! Using `host_websites="${host_websites}\n${config_name}"` instead resolved the issue.